# Is it possible to change the date format in Allure Reports?

Tags: report, date-format, allure

My Allure reports display the date in a MM/dd/yyyy format.
I would like to change the format to be dd/MM/yyyy.
Is it possible to set a different date format in allure reports?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can do this in the `settingsFactory.js`, which can be found at:

```
allure-generator\src\main\javascript\utils\settingsFactory.js
```

Here is an example of setting this to the `en` (English) and `au` (Australia) locale.

```js
import LocalStorageModel from '../data/localstorage/LocalStorageModel';

const globalSettingsDefaults = {
    language: 'en-AU',
    sidebarCollapsed: false,
    sideBySidePosition: [50, 50]
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, but where do I find this allure-generator\src\main\javascript\utils\settingsFactory.js?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Rob, and thank you for your contribution. I've updated your answer to include formatting for the code, path, and inline references. Please review so that you can use similar formatting in your future answers. This makes the answers easier to read and follow.

Comment: Also note that your `globalSettingsDefaults` JSON was malformed; it didn't include a closing brace. I fixed this as part of my edit.